# Is it possible to recover a wallet from Address and Password?

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet-security

I had an Electrum wallet on my laptop that broke, contrary to the usual "forgot my password" questions, I do have my password but I don't have the seed and the laptop is on repair and the data is not guaranteed to be intact, is there a way to access my wallet without the seed, but with the password and address?

Comment: If after the laptop repair your data are not intact and the seed is lost , there are a lot of hard disk data recovery services which might be able to recover your seed. This is possible because deleted data on hard disk are not actually deleted , they remain on hard disk until overwritten by new data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either

- the seed
- the wallet file and password

Nothing else will do, unfortunately.

Comment: What's the seed? Is "getwalletinfo.hdseedid" the seed?